# Solve heat equation with nonlinear term in matlab - Does my solution look reasonable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

> 4) Write a program to solve the following initial boundary value problem:
>   $$ v_t = 0.01 v_{xx} + 100 v (v-1) (.25 - v) $$
>   with $v_x(0,t) = v_x(1,t) = 0$ for all $t>0$, and
>   $$
> v(x,0) =
> \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
>   0\quad &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq .40 \\
>   a\quad &\text{if } .40 < x < .60 \\
>   0\quad &\text{if } .60 \leq x \leq 1.0
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
>   Solve this problem with $a = .20$ and with $a = .90$ for the time interval $0\leq t \leq 1$ and comment on the difference in the nature of the solution. Try to explain this difference in behavior.

I know how to solve $v_t=Cv_{xx}$ and I think I am ok on the Neumann BC ad the piece wise component, but I don't know how to account for the nonlinear term though. I imagine that I might want to use newton's method or Runge Kutta methods or something but I don't know what I would want to solve for. I am really just at a loss on this problem :(

UPDATE: I have found that to satisfy the Neumann conditions we need the following matrix I think:
[image]

Any idea if this looks reasonable for $a=0.3$? Each line is at an updated time.

[image]

Comment: What methods are you using to solve $v_t = C v_{xx}$?  Finite difference in both space & time?  Method of lines?  Finite element?  Something else?

Comment: Hi Kyle. I am trying to use finite difference methods. I will update my question with the progress that I have made

Comment: Why don't you just treat the linear terms implicitly and the nonlinear terms explicitly i.e an IMEX approach?

Comment: @Mattos I am not familiar with that approach unfortunately... Is it easy to learn?

Comment: I think so @MathIsHard :)  I'm not really sure what the standard reference is... however, two links from Googling are [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_and_implicit_methods) (it shows an example of applying IMEX to $\frac{dy}{dt} = y - y^2$) or [these lecture notes](https://www.math.utah.edu/~vshankar/5620/IMEX.pdf) written by V. Shankar.

Comment: @MathIsHard, I am not 100% certain, however, I am skeptical of this result.  There seems to be an instability... $||v(\cdot,0)||_{\infty} = 0.3$, but at later times $$||v(\cdot,t)||_{\infty} ~ 10^{155}$. :\  Could you describe the matrix you derived (or post an image of it) which incorporates Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: It was recommend to me to use this. See above.

Comment: It is only stable for certain k and h but it was the quickest to implement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting your derivation.  If you intended to use a simple IMEX (IMplicit EXplicit) approach, you should start with $\frac{u_j^{n+1} - u_j^n}{k} = \beta \left[ \frac{u_{j-1}^{n+1} - 2u_j^{n+1} + u_{j+1}^{n+1}}{h^2} \right] + R(u_j^n, x_j, t_n)$.  (The terms in square brackets are different than what you started with... they are evaluated at the $(n+1)$th rather than the $n$th time level.)  The eqn you started with is simply forward Euler applied to $u_t = \beta u_{xx} + R(u,x,t)$, which might explain the instability, given the strong nonlinearity $R(u,x,t) = 100u(u-1)(0.25-u)$.

Comment: @Kyle thank you. I will give that a try if the Forward Euler doesn't work out. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @Harry49 Thank you. You are totally right about the k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use an [explicit FD method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Example:_The_heat_equation) with centered differentiation in space, where $k$ is the time-step and $h$ the mesh size. Thus, if $v_j^n \simeq v(j h, n k)$, we have
$$
v_j^{n+1} = (1 - 2\lambda) v_j^{n} + \lambda (v_{j+1}^{n} + v_{j-1}^{n}) + k R(v_j^{n})\, ,
$$
where $R(v) = 100 v (v-1) (.25 - v)$ is displayed below, and $\lambda = 0.01 k/h^2$ is the Fourier number. The boundary conditions are discretized using centered finite differences:
\begin{aligned}
 v_{-1}^n &= v_{+1}^n \\
 v_{J_x+1}^n &= v_{J_x-1}^n
\end{aligned}
where $J_x = 1.0/h$.

[image: R]

In the case $R(v) = 0$, the numerical method is stable and convergent under the condition $\lambda \leq 1/2$. In the nonlinear case, the method writes as a nonlinear dynamical system ${\bf v}^{n+1} = {\bf f}({\bf v}^{n})$ with ${\bf f}$ nonlinear, which makes stability analysis more difficult.

Here is a Matlab code which implements the method, and the numerical solution for $a = .20$ and $a = .90$ at the final time $t = 1.0$:

```
% relaxation function
R = @(u) 100*u*(u-1)*(0.25-u);

% domain
Jx = 200;

% initial data
a = 0.9;

% data
h = 1/Jx;
x = -h:h:1+h;
lambda = 0.25;
k = h^2*lambda/0.01;
v = zeros(size(x));
v((0.4<x)&(x<0.6)) = a;
vtemp = v;

% initialization
figure;
clf;
h = plot(x,v);
xlim([0 1]);
ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('v');
t = 0;
ht = title(sprintf('t = %0.3f',t));

% loop
while t+k<1
    % scheme
    for j=2:Jx+2
        vtemp(j) = (1-2*lambda)*v(j) + lambda*(v(j-1)+v(j+1)) + k*R(v(j));
    end
    % boundary conditions
    vtemp(1)    = vtemp(3);
    vtemp(Jx+2) = vtemp(Jx);

    t = t+k;
    v = vtemp;
    set(h,'YData',v);
    set(ht,'String',sprintf('t = %0.3f',t));
    drawnow;
end
```

[image: Results]

Let us examine the relaxation part $v_t = R(v)$ (cf. [*splitting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strang_splitting)). From the graph of $R$, one can deduce that the long-time solution to the IVP $v(0) = .20$ is $v(\infty) = 0$, while the long-time solution to the IVP $v(0) = .90$ is $v(\infty) = 1.0$. This explains the different nature of the solutions for $a= .20$ and $a = .90$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will compare your code to what I came up with to see where I went wrong.

Comment: I went through the computations again and saw that my matrix wasn't right as you had said. Also in my code I wasn't updating the R(v) for each loop with the new values of the solution at that time. Thanks again for the help.